# How Do I Get poledit.exe Out Of Windows 2000 Service Pack 4?

Tags: samba, group-policy, windows-server-2000

I've read that I can get poledit.exe from Windows 2000 Service Pack 4, but have been unable to figure out how.

I've downloaded the service pack from Microsoft's website, "W2KSP4_EN.EXE", and extracted it using the "/x" option on the command line:

```
  W2KSP4_EN.EXE /x
```

Which produced an i386 folder with a bunch of files in it, but poledit.exe isn't there. Theres a "poledit.ex_", but changing the "_" to an "e" and trying to execute it results in the error:

```
The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction.
```

I'm trying to do this on a winXP Pro machine. I know I've gotten this to work before, but don't remember how I did it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use the expand.exe utlity to decompress that file.

Comment: I tried "expand.exe w2ksp4_en.exe extracted" and it just copied the entire file into the "extracted" directory, without extracting it.

Comment: @Nick: I believe you use expand on the extracted poledit.ex_ file, not on the service pack file.

Comment: Yes indeed, "expand.exe poledit.ex_ poledit.exe" as i remember.